# When I change the input, it doesn't send the variables

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

When I try to change any input value, it doesn't send the variables information.

Ex:
When I just send it with the fields already filled in from the input, it works.

But when I change any field, everything goes empty.

## LOG

OK:

```
{ id: '63aca9adeb91db1c46f32b23' }
{ period: 'teste', startId: '321' }
```

WITH PROBLEM:

```
{ id: 'undefined' }
{}
```

## REACT

```js
const { admin_users_token } = parseCookies();
const [loading, setLoading] = useState(false);
const [turma, setClassroom] = useState();

const handleChange = (f) => {
  setClassroom(f.target.value);
};

const handleSubmit = async (f) => {
  f.preventDefault();
  try {
    setLoading(true);
    const url = `${baseUrl}/api/novotec/classroom/edit/${turma._id}`;
    const { period, startId } = turma;
    const data = {
      period,
      startId,
    };
    const payload = {
      headers: { Authorization: admin_users_token },
    };
    const response = await axios.put(url, data, payload);
    toast.success(response.data.message, {
      style: {
        border: "1px solid #4BB543",
        padding: "16px",
        color: "#4BB543",
      },
      iconTheme: {
        primary: "#4BB543",
        secondary: "#FFFAEE",
      },
    });
  } catch (err) {
    let {
      response: {
        data: { message },
      },
    } = err;
    toast.error(message, {
      style: {
        border: "1px solid #ff0033",
        padding: "16px",
        color: "#ff0033",
      },
      iconTheme: {
        primary: "#ff0033",
        secondary: "#FFFAEE",
      },
    });
  } finally {
    setLoading(false);
  }
};
```

## FORM

```
{
  turma && (
    <form onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
      <div className="mt-1">
        <input
          type="text"
          name="period"
          value={turma.period}
          onChange={handleChange}
        />
        <div className="mt-1">
          <input
            type="text"
            name="startId"
            value={turma.startId}
            onChange={handleChange}
          />
        </div>
        <button type="submit">Salvar</button>{" "}
      </div>
    </form>
```

## API

```js
const handlePut = async (req, res) => {
  const { id } = req.query;
  const { period, startId } = req.body;

  try {
    const classe = await NovotecClassrooms.updateOne(
      {
        _id: id,
      },
      {
        period,
        startId,
      }
    );

    res.status(200).json({ message: "Turma atualizada com sucesso" });
  } catch (e) {
    res.status(400).json({
      error_code: "update_classrooms",
      message: e.message,
    });
  }
};
```

I need to understand what I'm doing wrong, why it's not passing the changed input values.

Comment: it seems that you're using the handleChange for both inputs. a code sandbox would help

Comment: Can you make a sandbox for this, it's hard to investigate

Comment: When there is a change on the inputs you store the field value which is a string, but when you are trying to get the value on the `handleSubmit` function, you destruct it like it's an object `const { period, startId } = turma;` 
So I guess this is the reason why you see it's empty

Comment: Tks guys..  i solved the problem.